# Using sed and delete last line

Tags: bash, sed

I'm using sed command to delete the first two line, but when I redirect the content to a file appear the number of rows. I don't know how can I delete it.

I execute:

```
sed '7,9d' mi_fichero.txt
```

And the result is:

(I write the last lines)

```
 /XTENT/D3/REPOSITORY/20120305/2201/65601/84/1330951636844_D3_448987414829688495_.indd.gz
 /XTENT/D3/REPOSITORY/20120308/2201/65601/22/1331198783835_D3_3411473776849856760_.indd.gz
 /XTENT/D3/REPOSITORY/20120308/2201/65601/158/1331220874606_D3_2742969984589497048_.indd.gz
 /XTENT/D3/REPOSITORY/20120313/2201/65601/0/1331626743284_D3_7551629114585379089_.indd.gz
 /XTENT/D3/REPOSITORY/20120309/2201/65601/92/1331295878839_D3_4724445611762228808_.indd.gz
(60 rows)
```

I want to delete the line (60 rows), Anybody can help me ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Whats your linux distro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '7,9d;$d' file
```

Comment: Sorry !! Works perfectly. I was confusing because I didn't see "-i" parameter :) Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

There is already a correct answer and this is not sed but an alternate way to do this using awk

```
awk -v nl=$(wc -l < mi_fichero.txt) 'NR!=7 && NR!=9 && NR!=nl {print $0}' mi_fichero.txt
```